# Stripe withdrawal action in rails marketplace app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm new to rails. I'm trying to create a rails marketplace where sellers can cash out their acquired funds from sales on the site.

I'm confused how to configure my withdrawal form and my orders controller.

When I simply just go to localhost:3000/withdrawal, a Stripe Recipient with just name is created on my Stripe dashboard without even completing the form. My form is nonexistent because everything I've tried for form_for generates an error.

I want the user to input their info and then choose to submit it, not create the recipient when "cash out" (which leads to the withdrawal path) is clicked.

The stripe documentation is helpful, but I'm not sure how to create my form.

Here is my withdrawal action in my orders controller. I'm wondering if I need a new action within withdrawal? But not sure if that's possible?

```
 def withdrawal
Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
token = params[:stripeToken]

recipient = Stripe::Recipient.create(
  :name => current_user.full_name,
  :type => "individual",
  :bank_account => token
  )

transfer = Stripe::Transfer.create(
  :amount => (@funds).floor,
  :currency => "usd",
  :recipient => @seller.recipient
  )
  end
```

And my withdrawal.html.erb. I know I am missing a form tag and submit, but everything I've tried just processes an error. I don't know what form_for to call. I've tried "order" but it results in an error.

```
   <div class="text-center">
       <h1>Bank Account Information</h1>


      <div class="form-group">
       <%= label_tag :name %>
       <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "name", class: "form-control" } %>
       </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <%= label_tag :withdrawal_amount %>
         <%= text_field_tag :withdrawal_amount, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "amount", class: "form-control" } %>
  </div>
       <div class="form-group">
              <%= label_tag :routing_number %>
              <%= text_field_tag :routing_number, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "routingNumber", class: "form-control" } %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= label_tag :account_number %>
         <%= text_field_tag :account_number, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' =>    "accountNumber", class: "form-control" } %>
       </div>
```

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to create this "cash out" action. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`form_for` is for model objects. If you're not using a model object, or don't want/need Rails to infer things from the model object, don't use `form_for`.

For simple forms, instead use one of:

- `form_tag` - Same syntax as `form_for` but without the model-related magic.
- A plain old `<FORM>` tag. ERB templates are, after all, just HTML with Ruby mixed in.

Answer (score 0):

Your view should look something like the following:

```
<%= form_tag withdrawl_path, method: :post do %>
  <input type="text" name="card[number]" />
  <!-- whatever fields you need for form -->
<% end %>
```

You will be able to access the submitted params via params[:card][:param_name] or use strong params and only permit params you need.

Use custom routes

```
get "/form" => "controller_name#action_for_form", as: :action_for_form
post "/withdrawl" => "controller_name#withdrawl", as: :withdrawl
```

Controller:

```
def action_for_form
    # whatever code you need to setup form
    @seller = Seller.find(params[:seller_id])
end

def withdrawl
    # withdrawl code here
end

private
def card_params
  params[:card].permit(:card_token, :other_params)
end
```

Its worth taking the time to understand the form tag and using Rails outside of the Railsy way of form submissions. It can get messy, but it allows for much more flexibility.